# Issues scraping HTML code with Selenium WebDriver: Returned URL and action values different from the console value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scripting

I hope I find you well.

As a newcomer to both Python and web scraping, I was hoping if you could help me understand an issue I'm encountering on a project I'm working on.

To give you some context, I'm currently designing a script which allows individuals living in France to automatically check for available time slots to schedule an appointment for the French citizenship application process in the district in which they reside. Since time slots are extremely hard to come by and, given user feedback, they come and go very quickly, the process becomes a source of constant frustration for many people.

The code below is an excerpt from the script which connects to the district's website, selects an available booth and returns the "action" parameter of the availability page. The `time.sleep` function is used to avoid overloading the proxy used by the website (since it's prone to 502 errors) and I'm printing both the current url and the action values to verify if they align with the values in the browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

url = "http://www.hauts-de-seine.gouv.fr/booking/create/4462/1"
booth_selection = "//input[@value='7070'][@name='planning']"
booking_selector = "//input[@value='Etape suivante'][@name='nextButton']"
browser = webdriver.Safari()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

booth_selection = browser.find_element_by_xpath(booth_selection)
booth_selection.click()
time.sleep(5)
booking_submit = browser.find_element_by_xpath(booking_selector)
booking_submit.click()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
page = browser.current_url
print(page)
agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36'}
page_response = requests.get(page, headers=agent)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.text, 'lxml')
action = soup.find('form', id='FormBookingCreate').get('action')
print(action)
time.sleep(10)
browser.close()
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be case since:

- As a URL, I still get the same starting url instead of "http://www.hauts-de-seine.gouv.fr/booking/create/4462/2"
- For the action value, I get "/booking/create/4462/1" instead of "/booking/create/4462/2" which leads me to assume that I will not be able to scrape the HTML of the resulting URL.

Here's a screenshot of Safari's console for reference: [HTML code of resulting page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOidF.png)

Could you please help me understand why that's the case and what can be done to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use requests? Couldn't you just pass browser.page_source directly into BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what you're looking for:-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
url = "http://www.hauts-de-seine.gouv.fr/booking/create/4462/1"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,executable_path=r'\\chromedriver')
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_class_name("Bligne").click()
browser.find_element_by_class_name("Bbutton").click()
page = browser.current_url
print(page)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
action = soup.find(id = 'FormBookingCreate').get('action')
print(action)
```

The output I get is:-

```
http://www.hauts-de-seine.gouv.fr/booking/create/4462/2
```

and

```
'/booking/create/4462/2'
```

So what I have done is I have used class names and id to pull the information required. You can ignore the options part if you want.

Answer (score -1):

kept getting 504 error, although you need to do some digging... It's because  of the cookies why can't direct access the other URL. Using selenium would be really slow, I would recommend just using `request` for these kinds of things.

```
import requests 
    headders = {"Host": "www.hauts-de-seine.gouv.fr",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": 1,
    "DNT": 1,
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Referer": "http://www.hauts-de-seine.gouv.fr/booking/create/4462/1",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "en,en-GB;q=0.9,id;q=0.8",
    "Cookie": "eZSESSID={theCookie}; xtvrn=${AnotherCookie}$;{AnotherCookie}=-; {AnotherCookie}=1"} 

html = requests.get("http://www.hauts-de-seine.gouv.fr/booking/create/4462/2", headers=headders)
```

Comment: The 504 error is likely due to the website being overloaded with requests. That said, the code you supplied does not seem to be working (tested on PyCharm) since it doesn't return the HTML of the next page. Furthermore, for the values of "Upgrade-Insecure-Request" and "DNT", they should be in a str format, i.e. framed with quotes. But thanks for the suggestion :)